# Loadrunner Web (click&script) vs. Web (http/html)

Tags: loadrunner

Recording a script in http/html protocol fails to record some clicking in a frame (where no data is submitted to the server). Is Web click and script a good candidate to capture this clicking as in i.e. checking a radiobutton within the frame? Are there any known drawbacks using click and script as opposed to http protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click and Script is an orphaned technology, which has been superseded by the TruClient components.   For new, go either TruClient or web|HTTP and leave the click and script possibilities in the quiver.  Or, if you need complete user interaction with the GUI, then you go GUI Virtual User or Citrix|RDP.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with James. I think the C&S protocols were halfway stepping stones to where they really wanted to go, TruClient. But if you really need the client-side interaction at the time it happens, you might not have luck with web|HTTP. As of this writing LR 11.52 has been out a while and LR 12 just came out, the TruClient protocols are starting to mature. And version 12 lets you try up to 50 vusers for free.